# rebasing my bookmark on top of another bookmark in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have a bookmark named X and a bookmark named Y. I would like to rebase Y on top of X. Basically I would like a stacked diff with Y on top of X and that Y parent is X.

Comment: How is the '.hgignore' tag related with this question? It seems you are simply asking for a rebase... so just rebase (you might need to activate that as extension in your .hgrc): rebase -sY -dX

Answer (score 8):

When you start with

```
o-o-B-1-2-X
     \-3-4-Y
```

you need `hg rebase -b Y -d X` to transform the history into

```
o-o-B-1-2-X-3'-4'-Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
hg rebase -b X -d Y
```

where `X` is the base and `Y` is the destination